# Rails update child from parent controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have this simple situation:

User model has_one client
I want to update client's attributes from user's update method (in controller)
Should I accept nested attributes from client and update all as one, or should I update client independently (maybe call client's edit url from here) ?

Not sure what is the best way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use nested attributes for update client record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to update the *child* entity, you should do that into the `ChildsController`.

You *can* update the child in the parent controller, but it is a violation of the REST principles. You are the ultimate authority in your code for what you can and cannot do, but following best practices will help you in the long run.

If you insist on following the dark side, I suggest you to just update the child without using the overcomplicated `nested_attributes` which use case is for a **simultaneous** update.

Comment: It should be named as `ChildrenController`.

Comment: I updated the child manually but it does not feel right indeed. I'm in an unusual case but I might be able to make it work Rest style. Thanks